# How I can scan and register classes with attributes using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

For example I want to register all classes with **Service** attribute using StructureMap

```
[Service]
public class A {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you are required to create a custom `IRegistrationConvention` found in the `StructureMap.Graph` Namespace.

**Implement the convention**

```
public class ServiceDiscoveryConvention
                                : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        // check if type has attribute
        // add to registry using the registry variable
    }
}
```

**Add the convention to the scanner**

```
Scan(cfg =>
       {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly(); // or whatever assemblies you are scanning
            cfg.Convention<ServiceAttributeConvention>();
        });
```

**Remarks**

If you are free on your decision you may want to use interfaces instead of attributes. Using an Interface you are able to provide a common contract for all classes and they are way easier to work with when the project grows.

Attributes have a tendency to spread all over your code, refactoring them can be a real pain. Interfaces have much better tooling support when it comes to refactoring.

I am using interfaces for a similar task (plugin system) a convention like

```
public class TypeScanner<T> : IRegistrationConvention
{
    private static readonly Type PluginInterface = typeof(T);

    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.IsAbstract || type.BaseType == null) return;
        if (PluginInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type) == false) return;

        registry.For(PluginInterface).Singleton().Add(instance);
    }
}
```

usage would be similar:

```
Scan(cfg =>
       {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly(); // or whatever assemblies you are scanning
            cfg.Convention<TypeScanner<IYourService>>();
        });
```

If your convention takes constructor arguments you can use `With`:

```
Scan(cfg =>
       {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly(); // or whatever assemblies you are scanning
            var convention = new SomeConvention(x,y,z);
            cfg.With(convention);
        });
```

Comment: conventions are great.  just try not to make it too magical.  the way you've named it makes it very intuitive to know what's going on in that convention, but i've seen some really horrendous things done in the name of abstraction.

Comment: @Nathan, can you explain yourself please?

Comment: i have absolutely nothing against this answer.  i was actually about to pen this myself when i saw his answer pop up.  i generally just don't like using aop/attributes.  they've always seemed a little too magical to me.  it seems like if something is a service, they should all have something in common, so have them all implement the same interface, and scan for that.  no attribute needed, right?  the abstraction comment was really just general advice.  abstraction is good to a point, but somewhere you have to draw the line between what's clever and what's easily maintainable.

Comment: If I'll create empty interface like `public interface I {}` and let all services inherit it just to mark that class is service instead of attribute, will this be correct? Or I shouldn't use empty interface?

Comment: It's ok, this would be called a marker interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern

Comment: @nathan - We used attributes where we work, originally i introduced them to get peoples head around the whole concept. But it's become such a burden, I'm in the process of just using the interfaces and removing anything that looks like IoC.Resolve<T>. Attributes are bad :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to register the type with StructureMap if you aren't going to retrieve it via an interface.

Given:

```
[Service]
public class A {}

[Service]
public class B {}
```

The following code will work just fine, and StructureMap will populate any constructor dependencies in A or B, without any special registration:

```
var instanceA = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<A>();
var instanceB = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<B>();
```